# Can I return JSON data over HTML files?

Tags: php, jquery, json

It really bugs me because I can't respond to client with echo.

I need to respond the following data with JSON,

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
$response = array();
$response['username'] = $user;
$response['password'] = $pass;
json_encode($response);
```

However, I need to do it via a HTML file, like:

```
Template::set('response', json_encode($response));
```

The reason is, my framework always requires a page output like:

```
Template::set('response', array());
```

otherwise it tries to execute it itself. (which either is an error page or a null html response)

So I can't respond with JSON headers and echo. I was basically trying to get a workaround. If there is no way I can accomplish this, I'll tweak my framework a bit to respond with headers, but I prefer using a little workaround if it's possible.

Ps. By the way, this is how my jQuery runs. I believe there are no issues here but I may be mistaken, so have a look at this either.

```
$("#doLogin").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent normal form submit
    $("#login-result").html('<img src="<%THEME%>images/loading.gif">');
    var formData = $("#loginForm").serialize();
    $.post("?page=login", formData, function(response)
    {
        alert(response.username);
        $("#login-result").html(response.username);
    },'json');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Can you try to elaborate on what you are hoping to accomplish and why?

Comment: I'll update my question topic, it'll be too long to reply here, a second.

Comment: @LyverKinkki: *"...it'll be too long to reply here..."* And even if it weren't, the correct way to improve a question is to edit the question.

Comment: What framework do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either modify the code of your framework, or accomodate to it.

I suggest you separating business logic and output. When processing the request, you should not do any echo, but prepare the output, and pass output variables to your template. Your template should run independently from your business logic, only depending on the variables you passed. This will make your code more readable and easily modifiable.

As for the solution to your current problem: I would extend the template framework by adding an option to pass an array, and the framework would render it as a json object. This will keep business logic and view separated, still giving you a simple solution to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could just circumvent what the framework is trying to do by doing:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
```

However, I'd be pretty surprised if the framework doesn't have the abilty to emit JSON built in.